# Is it possible to get an interaction ONLY model in R with imputed data?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, chi-squared, imputation

I would like to specify a model that ONLY includes an interaction term (between two categorical variables) in a regression using R.

Data was imputed using MICE.

Model looks something like:

```
              fit=with(data=imp, lm(Y~A*B))
```

as opposed to:

```
              fit=with(data=imp, lm(Y~A+B+A*B))
```

Of course, both models produce the same output that include the two main effects and interaction effects for all levels of categorical variables.

Is there any way to call an INTERCEPT ONLY model so I can obtain a LR Chi-square for the term in R?

Happy to supply any other piece of necessary information

UPDATED OUTPUT FOR

```
               fit=with(data=imp, lm(Y~A+B+A*B)) 

                 est        se          t       df     Pr(>|t|)       
 (Intercept)    0.3425228 0.1762006  1.9439361 255.8431 0.0529994367 
  A2           -0.1345402 0.2227383 -0.6040284 341.5315 0.5462257933  
  A3           -0.6581980 0.1999631 -3.2915965 279.1284 0.0011243787  
  A4           -0.5027917 0.2059671 -2.4411255 339.3560 0.0151521258 
  A5           -0.4467593 0.2774011 -1.6105175 247.5980 0.1085590048 
  B2           -0.6132881 0.3177545 -1.9300690 309.3768 0.0545122193 
  A2:B2         0.8859492 0.4109083  2.1560752 339.6231 0.0317795829 
  A3:B2         1.2385945 0.3724444  3.3255827 331.7505 0.0009811451  
  A4:B2         1.0152149 0.3903675  2.6006649 312.3651 0.0097468231  
  A5:B2         0.9094596 0.4441705  2.0475463 307.5421 0.0414537211
```

UPDATE USING SUGGESTED CODE:

```
            fit=with(data=imp, lm(Y~A:B))
```

- A is a 5 level variable, B is a binary (0, 1)
- A:B does leave out the main effects and produces all levels of categorical predictors (rather than n-1)

Question:

- summary(pool(fit)) does not work when A:B is used; so separate output for each imputed data is produced. Question: is there a possible way to pool all imputed sets when only A:B is called?

  ```
     ## summary of imputation 20 :

     Call:
     lm(formula = Y ~ A:B)

     Residuals:
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
     -2.1975 -0.6907 -0.1208  0.5958  3.9214 

    Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
   (Intercept)  0.12818    0.21814   0.588   0.5571  
         A1:B0  0.17252    0.27345   0.631   0.5285  
         A2:B0  0.07246    0.25964   0.279   0.7803  
         A3:B0 -0.46319    0.23698  -1.955   0.0513 .
         A4:B0 -0.32374    0.24517  -1.320   0.1874  
         A5:B0 -0.27642    0.29536  -0.936   0.3499  
         A1:B1 -0.45623    0.33321  -1.369   0.1717  
         A2:B1  0.35042    0.30480   1.150   0.2510  
         A3:B1  0.21691    0.27491   0.789   0.4306  
         A4:B1  0.13749    0.29015   0.474   0.6359  
          A5:B1       NA         NA      NA       NA  
         ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

     Residual standard error: 0.9755 on 400 degrees of freedom
     Multiple R-squared:  0.08071,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.06003 
    F-statistic: 3.902 on 9 and 400 DF,  p-value: 9.099e-05
  ```

Comment: 1. Don't call `lm()` without a `data` argument if you ever want to get fitted values on anything other than the original sample. 2. `y ~ a:b` is what you're after.

Comment: `a*b` is shorthand for `a + b + a:b`. If you just want the interaction term, use `a:b`.

Comment: Statistically speaking this might be a questionable idea, make sure you know why you are doing it and the consequences.

Comment: thank you @HongOoi. Is there a way to pool the new lm model above?( fit=with(data=imp, lm(Y~A:B))). Summary(pool(fit)) results in the following error: Error in pool(fit) : 
  Different number of parameters: coef(fit): 11, vcov(fit): 10

Comment: @griffnevo, I am trying to get a likelihood ratio chi-square value for each term in the model (two predictors and interaction effect)